# Debugging sandboxed solution?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, sandbox-solution, debugging

I know this is a novice question, but my sandboxed solution works on one site and not the other. How/where can I actually see the errors generated by some sort of report? Debugging simply takes me to the site where I can see that nothing is actually happening although the solution has been deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the developer dashboard for debugging your sandbox solution:

> The Developer Dashboard is an instrumentation framework introduced in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010. Similar in concept to ASP.NET page tracing, it provides diagnostic information that can help a developer or system administrator troubleshoot problems with page components that would otherwise be very difficult to isolate.

More info, including how to turn it on/off via powershell [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff512745%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For whatever odd reason, debugging suddenly works now. All I did was hit F5 and run like normal, and I haven't changed any other settings.